# Why is this $wpdb query looping 5 times?

Tags: wpdb

I want to only return one value for this query, it's in my `functions.php` file. The idea is to return a value that I need once `post_meta` has been updated. It's returning the same (correct) value *5 times*... I only want the value to be returned once.

```
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 
    function ( $mid, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
        $results = $wpdb->get_var(
            "SELECT meta_value FROM " . $table_name . 
            " WHERE meta_key = 'data19' AND post_id = " .$object_id. " " );
    }, 
    10, 4 );
```

Any ideas how I can get just one value returned? I've tried:

- adding `Group by` to the end
- adding `OBJECT_K` to the end
- using `SELECT DISTINCT`
- using `MAX` before each value
- using `FIRST` before each value
- using `wp_reset_query()`

and some more I can't even recall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the hook is probably running multiple times (e.g. once per meta field). You may need to qualify/filter your function like so…

```
add_action( 'added_post_meta', function ( $mid, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) {
  global $wpdb;

  if ( $meta_key != 'data19' ) {
    return;
  }

  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
  $results = $wpdb->get_var(
    "SELECT meta_value FROM " . $table_name . 
    " WHERE meta_key = 'data19' AND post_id = " .$object_id. " " );

}, 10, 4 );
```

Comment: `added_post_meta` is a WP hook, and should check `$meta_key != 'data19'` (not `$mid`) based on sql query...

Comment: `updated_{$meta_type}_meta` is the hook. It's called once per `add_metadata()` call on the `post` post type.

Comment: Yes- the hook was being called multiple times... once for each of the meta_value that were created. Using @MattvanAndel 'filter/qualify' idea, and replacing the code with what @bonger suggested... I now have the value being returned just once. So, when I inserted this as the qualification code: `if ( $meta_key != 'data19' ) {return;}` ... it worked perfectly. I've updated the code.